# How to use `ConstColumn` for optional values in the Slick

Tags: scala, slick

There is some table:

```
case class Thing(name: String, color: Option[String], height: Option[String])

class ThingSchema(t: Tag) extends Table[Thing](t, "things") {
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def color = column[Option[String]]("color")
  def height = column[Option[String]]("height")
  def * = (name, color, height) <> (Thing.tupled, Thing.unapply)
}
val things = TableQuery[ThingSchema]
```

For example, there are the following data in the `things` table:

```
|  name   |   color   | height |
+---------+-----------+--------+
|   n1    |  green    | <null> |
|   n1    |  green    | <null> |
|   n1    |  <null>   | normal |
|   n1    |  <null>   | normal |
|   n1    |  red      | <null> |
|   n2    |  red      | <null> |
```

I need to get the following result from the above data:

```
|  name   |   color   | height | size |
+---------+-----------+--------+------+
|   n1    |  green    | <null> |  2   |
|   n1    |  <null>   | normal |  2   |
|   n1    |  red      | <null> |  1   |
|   n2    |  red      | <null> |  1   |
```

To solve this task I use the following grouping queries:

```
SELECT name, color, null, count(*) AS size
FROM things
GROUP BY name, color

UNION ALL

SELECT name, null, height, count(*) AS size
FROM things
GROUP BY name, height
```

I've tried to create this query with the Slick:

```
val query1 = 
      things.groupBy(t => (t.name, t.color))
            .map { case ((name, color), g) => (name,color,None, g.size)} //Error#1

val query2 = 
      things.groupBy(t => (t.name, t.height)) 
            .map { case ((name, height), g) => (name,None,height,g.size)} //Error#1

val query = query1 ++ query2
```

But the above code isn't compiled, because the Slick can't define type for `ConstColumn` for the `None` values (see `//Error#1` comment in the above code).

This would work for the NOT-null values (such as `numbers`, `strings`), but doesn't work for Nullable values which are represented as `Option[String]=None` for example.

How to use `ConstColumn` for `None` values for this case?

[Here is the link to the same question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaquery/WnwuDaJzgg8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error I'd expect in this situation is a type-mismatch of some kind between `Option[String]` and `None.type` at the two `//Error` points in your code.

What you can do is give a type annotation on the `None`:

```scala
val query1 = 
      things.groupBy(t => (t.name, t.color))
            .map { case ((name, color), g) => (name,color, None: Option[String], g.size)}
```

That will be compiled into the `SELECT name, color, null, count` pattern you're using.

Answer (score 4):

I've found another solution for this task. Perhaps it will be useful for someone.

We can use `Rep.None[T]` or `Rep.Some[T]` to generate `ConstColumn` values for optional types.

This example works too:

```
val query1 = 
     things.groupBy(t => (t.name, t.color))
           .map { case ((name, color), g) => 
                        (name,color, Rep.None[String], g.size)
                }
```

This approach has two advantages:

1) We can assign to more general type. For example:

```
val field: Rep[String] = ...
val x: (Rep[String], Rep[Option[String]]) = (field, Rep.None[String])

// it is not compiled because a tuple has type (Rep[String], Option[String])
val y: (Rep[String], Rep[Option[String]]) = (field, None: Option[String])
```

2) This approach is a bit shorter